# Why does poured honey move periodically when reaching the surface it's poured upon?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, oscillators, viscosity

Here's the picture, known to most of us:

[image]

When honey is poured out of a container, as in the picture (look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YM09I7bhQMM) for the flow in motion), we see a kind of periodic flow of the honey when it comes to a stop at the surface, it's being poured upon. One can see a nice visualization of this effect [here](https://www.flowvis.org/2014/09/05/a-falling-stream-of-honey-piles-up-in-unstable-rope-coiling-color-inverted/) too. I thought an explanation was given there but it wasn't.
Intuitively, I can feel why it happens. But then again, it could have been the case that the honey keeps on flowing to just one side instead of making a circular or to-fro motion.

So, what's the physics involved? Can we apply the [Navier-Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equations or can we make use of the [Stokes flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow), which seems more appropriate in this case? How to apply it? Of course, we can always search for sanctuary in a TOE, but I think in this case...hmmm...

Comment: It's obviously related to the high viscosity of runny honey but good luck applying the Navier Stokes equations to this case!

Comment: The honey is viscous enough that this might be able to be modeled as a "rod" of honey that "buckles" once it reaches the spoon.

Comment: Or maybe the rope-coiling analogy is useful? The physics of ropes is easier than the physics of fluids (and I'm not sure you'd get this shape from a semirigid rod)

Comment: You can dive in [here](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.74.066306) and the references therein.

Comment: There's been a lot of great work investigating this, and several pop-sci articles. Googling "Physics honey pouring" is a good place to start.

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy That was a good suggestion!

Comment: @Daniel one can get pretty similar picture using a ribbon instead of a rope.

Comment: Hmm, but doesn't honey usually coil like a rope instead of folding like a ribbon? I think the picture in the question is actually a coil seen from the side.